# How do I connect a photodiode to a GPIO?

Tags: serial, raspberry-pi, gpio, photodiode

I'm trying to read serial data emitted through an IR led with a Raspberry Pi using an IR photodiode, but I'm not sure about the correct way to hook it up.

Unfortunately I don't have a part number for the photodiode, I got them as "generic wide band photodiode".

It will be placed at just some millimeters from the IR led and the signal data is at 4800bps, I'm pretty sure the signal will be good and strong.

After some googling I tried connecting +3.3V to the cathode, a 100kΩ resistor from the anode to ground, and the GPIO to the anode too, but it didn't work so I guess I'm doing something wrong.

I'd like to keep the thing as simple as possible, but it's ok if I have to throw a transistor in there (I have a couple of generic NPN and maybe also PNP lying around somewhere).

Comment: what's the part number of your diode? please provide it in the question, and provide a link to the datasheet too.

Comment: @VladimirCravero sorry I don't have that

Comment: Here is a little [article](http://maxembedded.com/2013/08/how-to-build-an-ir-sensor/) about home build digital IR sensor, may it will be helpful.